# gcsfuse is not updating the m3u8 file content

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

This issue only happens in gcs bucket . It works normally on AWS. Have you ever encountered this problem?

I mounted the /stream directory. When I check content of m3u8 file it is updated in the folder (OS side). But when I check in gcs bucket I see old entries that haven't been updated.

Logs:

```
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f2        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":623537580}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f4        connection.go:416] \u003c- LookUpInode (parent 1, name \"streamId.m3u8.tmp\", PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":623595043}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f4        connection.go:500] -\u003e Error: \"no such file or directory\"\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":623670095}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f6        connection.go:416] \u003c- CreateFile (parent 1, name \"streamId.m3u8.tmp\", PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":623721635}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x152: \u003c- CreateObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\")\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":623773994}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x152: -\u003e CreateObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\") (45.511231ms): OK\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":669291315}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f6        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK (inode 73)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":669353477}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f8        connection.go:416] \u003c- WriteFile (inode 73, PID 0, handle 37, offset 0, 269 bytes)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":669490752}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fa        connection.go:416] \u003c- SetInodeAttributes (inode 73, PID 52692, mtime 2023-05-04 08:19:36.666432164 +0000 UTC)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":669523887}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x153: \u003c- Read(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\", \u003cnil\u003e)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":669599309}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x153: -\u003e Read(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\", \u003cnil\u003e) (32.104214ms): OK\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":701695983}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003f8        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":701761602}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fa        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":701783989}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fc        connection.go:416] \u003c- FlushFile (inode 73, PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":701844422}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x154: \u003c- StatObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\")\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":701901715}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x154: -\u003e StatObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\") (32.064964ms): OK\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":733969875}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x155: \u003c- CreateObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\")\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":734002876}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"gcs: Req            0x155: -\u003e CreateObject(\"streamId.m3u8.tmp\") (55.689975ms): OK\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789696549}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fc        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789780223}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fe        connection.go:416] \u003c- ReleaseFileHandle (PID 0)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789844029}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000400        connection.go:416] \u003c- GetInodeAttributes (inode 1, PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789882126}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x000003fe        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789907586}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000400        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK ()\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789945748}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000402        connection.go:416] \u003c- LookUpInode (parent 1, name \"streamId.m3u8.tmp\", PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":789988851}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000402        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK (inode 73)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":790069198}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000404        connection.go:416] \u003c- LookUpInode (parent 1, name \"streamId.m3u8\", PID 52692)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":790123842}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000404        connection.go:498] -\u003e OK (inode 74)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":790202140}
{"name":"root","levelname":"DEBUG","severity":"DEBUG","message":"fuse_debug: Op 0x00000406        connection.go:416] \u003c- ForgetInode (inode 74, PID 0)\n","timestampSeconds":1683188376,"timestampNanos":790240257}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mrtux01 for reaching out!

Can you please confirm, which file you want to see updated on GCS `streamId.m3u8.tmp` or `streamId.m3u8`?

> > As per the gcsfuse logs, we can see the Flush file for `streamId.m3u8.tmp` but not for `streamId.m3u8`. Hence, you can see the `streamId.m3u8.tmp` on GCS unless deleted.

> > For `streamId.m3u8` file, we can only see `ls` call. Since, logs are not complete, so we can't say this file would be updated on GCS or not. Can you please share the complete logs if this is the case?

-Prince

Comment: Thanks for your comment. streamId.m3u8 > this file.